# first time trying tdd. which tests should I write?

Tags: testing, tdd, bdd

I'm working on an application for access control on gyms.
I want to make all this app testable, but it's my first time with TDD/BDD. I don't exactly know which tests should I create.

Maybe tests from user's perspective? Something like:

- As a visitor, I want to enter gym.
- As a visitor, I want to exit gym.
- As a visitor, I want to enter two times (this should return exception).
- ...
- As administrator, I want to import list of visitors.
- As administrator, I want to clear visitors list.
- As administrator, I want to know who is on the gym.
- ...

Or maybe tests from developer's perspective? Something like:

- testVisitorEnterOnGymReturnTrue()
- testVisitorExitGymReturnTrue()
- testVisitorExitGymBeForeEnteredToGetException()
- testVisitorEnterGymTwoTimesToGetException()
- testAdministratorImportListOfVisitorsReturnTrue()
- testAdministratorClearListOfVisitorsReturnTrue()
- testAdministratorShowWhoIsOnTheGymNowReturnArray()

Which kind of tests should I create before start coding?

Comment: Those two perspectives seem to be largely interchangeable as given. That said, this might do better on [Programmers.SE] or even [SQA.SE], since it's less about specific code problems and more about testing methodology.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitely test from your users' perspective and never from your own (unless you are your own customer).

Working this way you have the basis for a conversation with your customer, which I find especially useful in finding those rarely thought of corner cases.  The conversations will be in terms your user understands and will translate back to more tests.

Answer (score 0):

I would start with unit testing my classes. 
it is by nature a developer perspective, you verify that each method in your class does what you expect her to do.
you will be surprised how many bugs you can find this way.
It is highly recommended to write your test while you write your code and not after that.